# Android image slider like Ios

Tags: android

How can I make an android image slider that contains two parts. One part is an horizotal image slider (thumnail), the second part is an original image of the selected image.
This look like ios horizontal view in ios:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Gallery` and `ImageView`

1: Make a layout :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="70"/>

    <Gallery
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2: Initialize Gallery with adapter.

3: Define onItemClickListener for gallery items where you need to change imageView given above.

Alternatively, you can use the complete code given here :
[LINK](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html)  (similar to what you are trying to do)